# How to replace one line in multiple file on linux terminal?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a folder containing multiple files, each file contains a string like

```
  "tree": "/a/anything-here/b/"
```

for each file I need to replace the content between inner `"//"` in this case `"anything-here"` with a string

I am using `sed` command with no success, could you help me?

```
sed -i 's/"root": a/b" .
```

Comment: Looks like a JSON field? Don't use non-syntax aware parsers like sed in case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this sed:

```
s='"tree": "/a/anything-here/b/"'
sed -E 's~"(/[^/]*/)[^/]*/~\1new-string/~' <<< "$s"
```

```
"tree": /a/new-string/b/"
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk -v str='new-string' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {$3 = str} 1' <<< "$s"
```

```
"tree": "/a/new-string/b/"
```